# How to get current 'page' and pass as param in React Router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I get the current "page", which is `":name"` below in the `Route`, and pass that as a prop to the `<Food>` component? For example, if I'm on `"/food/egg", I should be passing` "egg"` to the component. I cannot find the answer with so many versions out there.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import Food from './Food';
import { Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/food/:name" element={<Food name= 
 {something here?} />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you not able to use the `useParams` hook in the `Food` component? "i cannot find the answer with so many versions out there." - well, you only need to check one version really, the one you have installed. Here's a link to documentation for [dynamic segments](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#dynamic-segments) including how to access the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

From react router docs:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProfilePage() {
  // Get the userId param from the URL.
  let { userId } = useParams();
  // ...
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="users">
        <Route path=":userId" element={<ProfilePage />} />
        <Route path="me" element={...} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

So you just need to use the `useParams` hook which returns an object like `{ id: "1234", name: "John Doe" }`.